# Content loaded via Ajax breaks buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html page which gets loaded via ajax, the newly loaded html content has the following html. It typically works great when I load the html first and then initialize the javascript.

```
<a href="" class="ajax-button" data-url="/account/change-password">Change password</a>
```

My js:

```
$('.ajax-button').on('click', OnLoadContent);

function OnLoadContent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pageurl = $(this).data('url');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: pageurl,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#content-container").html(data);
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl}, '', pageurl);
        },
        error: function(response) {
           alert("ERROR:" + response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

However since it's new html content that's being loaded I think the problem is the javascript already exists when the html content is loaded via ajax, so the click functionality doesn't work unless I click again. I'm wondering how I can fix this?

Comment: It must/should be a drinking game ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Delegate](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** the click higher up the dom...

`$('body').on('click', '.ajax-button', OnLoadContent);`